# ansible: run one of playbook task as role dependency

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have a role named A and another role named B.
I want to be able to run a specific task from role B before role A is taking place.
If I put role B as a dependency of role A all B's tasks is played before A.
Any ideas?

Comment: I only have the idea to work with tags but that's not satisfying at all I guess.

Comment: I also think tag is the key here but I am not sure how to work it. If I add a tag to that specific task, how I make ansible to look for it?

Comment: The only way is to pass it on the command line `--tags "foo"`, but beside that specific task in role B all your tasks in role A would need to have that tag `foo`. Which is pretty ugly.

Comment: You could break the task out into yet another role, role C, and have C be a dependency of both roles A and B.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Bruce P if you have a common task in both roles, A and B, you should extract it into its own separate role. In general, it is considered a good practice to box various components into roles, no matter how small a particular role may be.

If you can call the role 'Common', for example, when you run both roles, whoever is reading your playbook will be able to identify the step as a common config/task. Readability and reusability galore!

Answer (score 1):

You would tag your desired tasks and then as shown in http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_tags.html you would:

```
roles:
  - { role: Role_B, port: 5000, tags: [ 'web', 'foo' ] }
```